# Caliper guide pin position on 2001 Mitsubishi Eclipse Sdyder GT Conv

Tags: mitsubishi

I recently replaced the rotors and pads on my Mitsubishi Spyder GT conv. My question is about the position of the caliper guide pins. 2 of the pins have a recess on the end for new seal rings and two of the pins are solid with no recess. I kept track of their position so I could put them back the same way. But, the ones with the recess on the front calipers were in the top position and the rear ones were in the bottom position. The pins are exactly the same diameter and length.

This seems odd, but when I put the new seal ring on them none of them would fit back into the guide holes. I did not want to force them so I left them off for now. (The old ones were pretty mashed up to the point where I had to dig what was left of them out with a curved pick). I doubt they were actually in place prior to dis-assembly.

Can anyone tell me which position the pins with the recess should be in? (Top or bottom) Should they be the same for the front and rear? Lastly, should I force them in with the new seals in-place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZwjOAqYkL4) will show you a pad replacement on the Eclipse. You will see the fitment of the pins and boots.